# Error in the res/values-v11 folder of android-support-v7-appcompat Android

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat

I am new to android programming. I am trying to import the android-support-v7-appcompat into my workspace but I run into an error. The error is in the `res/values-v11/themes_base.xml` and other .xml files in the folder `res/values-v14 and res/values-v21`.
The error message is

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v11    line 359    Android AAPT Problem"

Any suggestions?

Comment: clean & build the project

Answer (score 1):

include liberay 'android-support-v7-appcompat' in your project.

1. got to project properties
2. Add library android-support-v7-appcompat

if still it does not work then try to add jar 'android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'
to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
select library project android-support-v7-appcompat>> Right click and go to properties >> Select Android and pick your latest sdk 5.0.(Api lvl 21).

Answer (score 0):

I just wanna elaborate on it and give a solution for all IDE's (Eclipse, IntellJ and Android Studio) even if the errors differentiate slightly.

**Prerequirements**

Make sure that you've downloaded the latest extras as well as the Android 5.0 SDK via the SDK-Manager.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error :

"error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name"

in library Project android-suppot-v7-appcompat.
To be specific, I got errors at multiple places:

1. android-suppot-v7-appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml
2. android-suppot-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml
3. android-suppot-v7-appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml
4. android-suppot-v7-appcompat/res/values-v11/styles_base.xml
5. android-suppot-v7-appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base_text.xml

the problem was : My Project Build Target was Android 4.4.2 (API 19), whereas few of the themes/styles which were included in above files were above Android 4.4.2 (API 19).

Solution : 
Right Click on android-support-v7-appcompat, go to properties and click on android Tab

[image]

**Change Project Build Target from Android 4.4.2 (API 19) to Android 5.0.1 (API 21).
Changing it to 4.4W.2 (API 20) will give multiple errors to all your apps and eclipse so you can ignore it.**